# Return item at supermarket (consumer's fault?)

Tags: halacha, food, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, mistakes, transactions

Say I buy a food item at a supermarket and later discover it was opened. I then am unsure whether I opened it or not. Is one allowed to return it if there is doubt (one is not completely sure) that one may have forgotten and opened it?

A second example is say I buy an item that I believe to be kosher. I then realize it is not kosher after opening it but just before eating it. Is one allowed to return this item as well or should it just be thrown out because it was the fault of the consumer for not being more careful?

Comment: Your first question will depend on the company's return policy.

Comment: Agree with Double AA - Opened items are normally not returnable unless defective, but many places see customer service as top of the priority list and so are willing to accept returns, even of opened items. The question becomes whether you are allowed to benefit from the store's generous policy. Presumably this would only be acceptable on a one-off basis. To _exploit_ the policy on a frequent basis strikes me as being dubious.

Comment: To make things very simple ,is just ask the store owner/manager, this usually solves all doubts.

Comment: Putting aside store policy and Dina d’Malchusa, why isn’t this a classic case of המוציא מחברו? Particularly since, if the owner claims that they’d never sell an open bag, you possibly end up with ברי ושמא ברי עדיף.

Answer (score 1):

R Avrohom Ehrman ([The laws of interpersonal relations](https://www.artscroll.com/Products/JTVH.html), from p. 399) has a chapter devoted to the laws of returning objects. The summary is that sales are final unless the seller willingly accepts the item in return, and the buyer is forbidden to pressure him to do so. **In your case, you are permitted to return the objects but would have to tell the seller what happened and see if he is willing to accept the return.**

Specifically, R Ehrman writes

> - To "reverse" a sales transaction is, in reality, to perform an entirely new transaction, in which the item is actually sold back to
>     the original seller
> - This new sale is like any other transaction, both parties must agree to it, and each one is forbidden to pressure the other to
>     conclude a sale against his will
> - If the prevailing practice in the locality is to accept returns, or if the parties make an explicit agreement at the time of the sale to
>     allow returns, then it is permitted

He then lists a varies of reasons one could return merchandise (e.g., defective merchandise, mistaken amounts, damaged food products)

Comment: If the item had been open already it would be a Mekach Taut not a return transaction, no?

Comment: But in this question the fault (or at least a reasonable amount of probability) is with the buyer not the seller. I understand *mekach taut* as a faulty product or transaction but see the title of the question

Comment: This seems to be a Safek Mekach Taut if there is such a thing. He's not sure if it came open or he opened it.

Comment: Right, so you can't go back and return it *stam*. You have to tell the seller of the doubt and see if he is willing to accept a return. The second case in the question is clearer: the buyer made a mistake, the seller didn't, it can still be returned if the seller is willing to agree to it.

Comment: How do you know you need the seller's permission for a Safek Mekach Taut? Maybe you can return it and let him try and prove you wrong

Comment: Because if the buyer is mistaken and it is not *mekach taut* then you can’t return just like this and the rules above apply. And if the buyer can’t resolve the doubt himself then he needs to disclose to the seller. I have a *shiur* in Choshen Mishpat in 30 minutes and plan to ask the dayan. Happy to report back

Comment: You have no proof that he needs to disclose. The transaction is Safek Batel already. Why should he lose out? כל דאלים גבר!

Comment: @DoubleAA I asked the dayan. He related the case to the one of buying a cow that might be a *tereifa*. Since cows are sometimes *tereifot*, if one buys under the presumption it is *kosher* and discovers it is a *tereifa*, one can return the cow. But here. since most items in supermarkets are not open, and since one is not sure it was opened, one has to go to the seller and disclose the doubt when asking for a return. In the second case, if the buyer believed it was kosher but the item was never kosher to start with, one has to disclose when returning....

Comment: ...  If one thought it was kosher but there was a fault in the product and it was not, then it is a straight return (although the latter is not how I understand the question here)